# Many JSON requests not works in for

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I found this implementation of realtime JSON ticker
[FTC/BTC BTC-e realtime ticker JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marcetin/rW4L2/1/)
As you can see it works fine.

But i need to get all tickers from this site in realtime.
I do next (html):

```
<div>BTC/USD <span id="p0"></span></div>
<div>BTC/RUR <span id="p1"></span></div>
<div>BTC/EUR <span id="p2"></span></div>
<div>LTC/BTC <span id="p3"></span></div>
<div>LTC/USD <span id="p4"></span></div>
<div>LTC/RUR <span id="p5"></span></div>
<div>USD/RUR <span id="p6"></span></div>
<div>EUR/USD <span id="p7"></span></div>
<div>NMC/BTC <span id="p8"></span></div>
<div>NVC/BTC <span id="p9"></span></div>
<div>TRC/BTC <span id="p10"></span></div>
<div>PPC/BTC <span id="p11"></span></div>
<div>FTC/BTC <span id="p12"></span></div>
```

And next (js):

```
$(function (){
    startRefresh();
});

function startRefresh() {
    setTimeout(startRefresh, 10000);

    var ops = new Array('https://btc-e.com/api/2/btc_usd/ticker','https://btc-e.com/api/2/btc_eur/ticker','https://btc-e.com/api/2/btc_rur/ticker','https://btc-e.com/api/2/ltc_btc/ticker','https://btc-e.com/api/2/ltc_usd/ticker','https://btc-e.com/api/2/ltc_rur/ticker','https://btc-e.com/api/2/usd_rur/ticker','https://btc-e.com/api/2/eur_usd/ticker','https://btc-e.com/api/2/nmc_btc/ticker','https://btc-e.com/api/2/nvc_btc/ticker','https://btc-e.com/api/2/trc_btc/ticker','https://btc-e.com/api/2/ppc_btc/ticker','https://btc-e.com/api/2/ftc_btc/ticker');

    for(var i = 0; i < ops.length; i++) {
    $.getJSON('http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20json%20where%20url%3D%22' + encodeURIComponent(ops[i]) + '%22&format=json', function (data) {
     $('#p'+i).html(parseFloat(data['query'].results.ticker.last).toFixed(6));
});
}
```

And it not works.
How can i get all tickers in realtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `i` has been reassigned by the time your callback gets executed (13 times, in fact). `i` is set to `13` by the time your request is complete. `13` instead of `12` because `i++` gets executed one final time before the loop closes. Since `#p13` doesn't exist, you see nothing occur.

You need to rearchitect your code, or use [JavaScript closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures).

Here's an example with closures to correct your script:

```
for(var i = 0; i < ops.length; i++) {
    // Create a custom callback
    var callback = (function(){
        // Assign i to a local variable j
        var j = i;
        // Create a callback function with our local variable j
        return function(data){
            $('#p'+j).html(parseFloat(data['query'].results.ticker.last).toFixed(6));  
        }
    })();

    // Give our new "custom" callback as the second argument
    $.getJSON('http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20json%20where%20url%3D%22' + encodeURIComponent(ops[i]) + '%22&format=json', callback);
}
```